# Puffin, open the browser in fullscreen, TheaterMode, directly

Tags: ios, iphone, flash

Can I construct a URL to tell Puffin to open a flash app directly in fullscreen (a.k.a. "Theater Mode")?

I am building an IOS app and need to open a browser that has Flash capabilities. Puffin seem to be working well. I am using a custom url: `puffin://.....` in order to open the link. Is there a way to have the link enter the **full-screen**, aka TheaterMode, by default?

There is `window.puffinDevice.notify("EnterTheaterMode")` option which I won't be able to use since I am not using any javascript in my native code. But is there a way to send **TheaterMode** as a parameter?